# Erro ao usar o comando add-migration. Usando json como arquivo de configuração

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, migrations

Bom dia!

Ao realizar o comando add-migration, para fazer as migrações, estou recebendo o sequinte erro:

```
Add-Migration : Exception calling "AddFromFile" with "1" argument(s) : "'basePath' 
        não pode ser uma cadeia de caracteres vazia("") nem começar com o caractere nulo.
        Nome do parâmetro: basePath"At line:1 char:1
        + add-migration Initial
        + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationE
            xception
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException,Add-Migration
```

Minha classe context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        ////////////////////////// MAPEAMENTOS ////////////////////////
        #region FluentAPI

        #region Barcos

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
           .ToTable("Barcos");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
            .Property(e => e.Nome)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(150)")
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
            .Property(e => e.CapacidadeAgua)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
             .Property(e => e.CapacidadeOleo)
             .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
             .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
             .Property(e => e.SapId)
             .HasColumnType("varchar(10)")
             .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
            .Ignore(b => b.ValidationResult);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
            .Ignore(b => b.CascadeMode);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
           .HasOne(b => b.CategoriaBarco)
           .WithMany(c => c.Barcos)
           .HasForeignKey(b => b.CategoriaBarcoID)
           .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
            .HasOne(b => b.TipoOperacao)
            .WithMany(b => b.barcos)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.TipoOperacaoID)
            .IsRequired();






        #endregion

        ////////////////////////// FIM MAPEAMENTO BARCOS////////////////////////

        #region CategoriaBarco

        modelBuilder.Entity<CategoriaBarco>()
           .ToTable("CategoriaBarco");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
        .Ignore(b => b.ValidationResult);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
            .Ignore(b => b.CascadeMode);


        #endregion


        #region TipoOperação

        modelBuilder.Entity<TipoOperacao>()
           .ToTable("TipoOperacao");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
        .Ignore(b => b.ValidationResult);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Barco>()
            .Ignore(b => b.CascadeMode);



        #endregion

        #endregion


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        optionsBuilder.UseOracle(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));


    }





}
```

}

Meu json file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=YOURSERVERNAME;   Database=YOURDATABASENAME; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

},

```
 "Logging": {
   "IncludeScopes": false,
     "LogLevel": {
     Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Information"
}
```

}
}

O erro diz que o basepath está vazio, mas não está
Eu ainda não tenho as conexões do banco, pq ele vai ser online e ainda não passaram as informações, pode ser isso o problema? 
Acho estranho pq para fazer as migrations, eu acho que não precisa de um banco (eu acho)

Comment: Conseguiu resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Verifique a estrutura do seu projeto em Propriedades > Aplicativo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois verifique se essa versão está instalada no seu computador:

C:/Program Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]